# Submit datepicker value concatenate with another input save in one input name

Tags: jquery, url, datepicker, submit, concatenation

I am doing a web site for a restaurant, and my reservation form submits to 'open table'. In order to submit the good url I need to concatenate a Datepicker value (jquery plugin) with the time value of another form.
Open table needs that to get inside the name input "d".

Something like this:`d=9%2f20%2f2012+9%3a30+PM`

So I created a function that will concatenate to a parsed datepicker and time inside d.

```
function reservation(){
    var newValue = $('#datepicker').val() +' '+$('#heures').val();
    $('#datepicker').val(newValue);
    return true;
       }
```

the result that i have is this: `d=27%2F09%2F2012+12%3A30+PM+12%3A30+PM+12%3A30+PM+12%3A30+PM+12%3A30+PM+12%3A30+PM`

I dont understand why I got the time repeating 5 extra times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function reservation i make is working, It was a Date format problem with Datepicker. Open Table reservation was waiting for MM/DD/YY while i was submitting DD/MM/YY.

So i just had to put this code to get the good date Format

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use .val() to set the date. You need to use the method provided by autocomplete plugin to do that try this..

```
function reservation() {
    var newValue = $('#datepicker').datepicker( "getDate") + ' ' + $('#heures').val();
    $('#datepicker').datepicker( "setDate" , newValue )
    return true;
}​
```

Something like this..

But to concatenate the dates you need to convert them in to datetime objects and then concatenate.. Because the .val() method return a string .. 
So basically you are concatenating 2 strings  which is wrong in this case...

Can you give a clear example of newValue when you want to combine these 2 dates

UPDATE .. Try this

```
function reservation() {
    alert('Date Picker value : ' + $('#datepicker').datepicker( "getDate"));       
    alert('Form Date value : ' + $('#heures').val());
}​
```

What do you get in the alert??

Comment: Thanks to you but still dont work. This gives me a console error !

Comment: Here is what the alert give me:Date Picker value : Thu Sep 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) and Form Date value : 8:00 PM

Comment: It looks like datePicker have hours built-in and not just the date. Thaanks that's a good track!

Comment: k.. Now what is the value that you are expecting to come up when you add these two dates

Comment: something like this d=27%2F09%2F2012+12%3A30+PM  (27 09 2012 12:30pm)

Comment: What is the Form Date value : 8:00 PM .. Does it have only time and no date ??

Comment: No it's 2 forms. 1 datepicker and an other one for the time.

Comment: How is it that Thu Sep 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)  ANd  : 8:00 PM be equal to  (27 09 2012 12:30pm